# Is there a way to find the weeknumber within the year using PHP?

Tags: php, date

Is there a way to find the weeknumber within the year using PHP?

Comment: In what way? Do you mean the first week of the year is week 1, and the last week 53? How do you define a week? (i.e. what day does it start on?) What language are you working in? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've removed your self-answer, and posted what you wanted to do as a community wiki answer - feel free to edit it to improve the wording.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), using the `W` format string, which returns:

> ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday (added in PHP 4.1.0)

e.g.

```
date("W");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try date('W');
http://my2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most standard is called GPS Week Number, 
see http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/CORS/Gpscal.html

Current week ID is 1578.